# How to get Bootstrap's column full browser height with fixed position?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I need to make a slide in that when the user clicks on a specific button appears from the right. And I'm making it with this html structure with Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

It needs to have a fixed position, I assume and a right:0; so it sticks to the right side. And I also need it to be full browser height. The thing is, if I use this CSS, it stretches the width of the card as well as the height:

```
.card {
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```

I've also noticed that the bottom of the content tends to be hidden on smaller screens. It's a slide in, I need it to always be visible 100%, while still being full height. Is it possible? And if so, what am I doing wrong, and what should I be doing instead? Can someone please take a look at my code and let me know?

```css
.card {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #29292b;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration-color: #757575;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="card rounded-0 border-0">
    <div class="card-header border-0 p-0">
      <button type="button" class="close p-2">
      <span aria-hidden="true">x close</span>
    </button>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x200" class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="..." alt="Card image cap" height="200">
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-header -->

    <div class="card-block py-4 px-3">
      <h4 class="card-title mb-2">Title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Text
        <span>Text</span>
        <span>Text</span>
      </p>

      <h4 class="card-title mb-2">Title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Text</p>

      <h4 class="card-title mb-2">Title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Text</p>

      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 py-3" id="exampleTextarea" rows="6" placeholder="Placeholder text here..."></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-block -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.card -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us a pic of how you want it to look? [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjrVxy)

Comment: I don't have an image, but I want the card to be full height while the content doesn't overflow on smaller screens. I've tried using 100vh, but that messes up everything on anything other than desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull it off by adding positive and negative padding like this:

```
.col-md-3 {
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100%;
}
```

jsbin:    http://output.jsbin.com/gajilaj

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way to go? It seems a little messy? I've tried using 100vh, but that creates a mess on mobile too. :/